# What's wrong with my searchbox?

Tags: html, css

[image]

This searchbox should take in the right side of the topbar.

**I want to take this search box in the right position as shown in udemy complete web dev 2.0 BBC-Clone css1 lecture.

This is as same as shown in udemy course, But I can't understand why it's not working here**

**This course is by Rob from udemy**

```css
#topbar {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.topbar-section {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#signin-image {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  float: left;
}

#signin-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 14px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#wigglyline {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}

#bell {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 9px 8px;
}

#bell-div {
  float: left;
}

.topbar-menu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
  height: 27px;
}

#more-arrow {
  width: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#searchbox {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
  float: left;
}

#magnifying-glass {
  height: 27px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Technology:BBC-News</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="topbar">

    <img id="logo" src="images/bbc-logo.png" alt="">

    <div id="signin-div" class="topbar-section">

      <img id="signin-image" src="images/signinimage.png" alt="">

      <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>

    </div>


    <div id="bell-div">
      <img id="wigglyline" src="images/wigglyline.png" alt="">

      <img id="bell" src="images/bell.png" alt="">
    </div>


    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
      News
    </div>


    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
      Sport
    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
      Weather
    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
      iPlayer
    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
      TV
    </div>

    <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
      More

      <img id="more-arrow" src="images/more-arrow.png" alt="">
    </div>


    <div class="topbar-section">

      <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search">

      <input type="image" id="magnifying-glass" src="images/search.png" alt="">

    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It appears fine to me. Try zooming out (ctrl + scroll on chrome) to see if it displays correctly to you. If so, you're exceeding the resolution of your display (which is something you should always be looking out for, check responsive design).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both inputs inside a div like so :

```
    <div id="search_icon">
        <input id="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search">

        <input type="image" id="magnifying-glass" src="images/search.png" alt="">
    </div>
```

I decided to give the div an id named search_icon.

Add the below css to your style

```
 #search_icon{
 position: relative;
 }

 #searchbox{
 width: 100%;
 }

 #magnifying-glass{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right 0;
 width: 25px;
 height: 26px;
 background-color: #a9a9a9;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

better used background short hand,

```
  #searchbox {
      background: #0db9f0 url('magnifier.png') center right no-repeat;
      border: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: 14px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px 0 5px;
      float: left;
    }
```